# Dúvida sobre os espaços em branco dentro do código PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou fazendo a conexão com `prepared statments` pra inserir muitas variáveis, e em alguns casos to demorando um tempão pra achar os erros, e agora empaquei em um aqui e me bateu uma dúvida:

> Os espaços em branco fazem diferença, posso quebrar linhas e dar
>   espaços tranquilamente?

Por exemplo, posso fazer:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,
    'sisss
    siiii
    iissi
```

Ou tem que ser:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sissssiiiiiissi ....
```

O mesmo para as variáveis e declaração de campos. Eu estou colocando de 3 em 3 em cada linha pra tudo, pra dar pra contar mais fácil e visualizar a falta de alguma variável etc...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabela(
campo1, campo2, campo3,
campo4, campo5, campo6 ....
```

Só os `values` que to colocando de 10 em 10:

```
VALUES
(
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ....
```

No caso do erro em questão, eu já conferi um milhão de vezes, então sei que não está faltando nada, tudo tem 138oooo!! (:/) Daí acho que deve ser algum erro na identação, porque ficam espaços e quebras de linhsa demais...

O erro é o seguinte:

> "Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of
>   bind variables"

(Este `number of bind variables` são os `?, ?`, ou são são os `ssss` . Tem alguma forma de saber pelo menos de qual é a diferença, se de um campo ou de 20?)

Então aqui no caso a pergunta é: os espaços em branco podem estar afetando o código? Como o PHP interpreta os espaços em branco dentro do script (eu pesquisei, mas só acho explicações sobre o `trim()` :) :/ ) ?

Comment: acho que não é o caso de usar trim().. deve ser devido as quebras de linha no parâmetro de definição de tipos sissssiiiiiissi.. REmova as quebras de linha ou outros caracteres inválidos desse parâmetro.

Comment: haha não, é que eu pesquisei sobre "espaços em branco no php" no google, e só recebi resulytados sobre o `trim()` rsrsr Vou fazer o teste...

Comment: o certo seria busca no google pela mensagem de erro "Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables"  .  Sempre que ver uma mensagem de erro, apenas copie e joga no google, que lhe dará um resultado mais próximo. Normalmente vai cair num link do stackoverflow kkk

Comment: Sim, eu fui em todas da primeira página pelo menos rsrsr quase todas no SO, mas meu problema era este que vc falou mesmo... pq agora mudou o erro, tá gravando, mas -1 linhas lol... acho que vou fazer outra pergunta sobre isso se não resolver aqui, mas este problema que tava sumiu depois que coloquei os #$%$%&*& `ssss` na mesma linha... :-D valeu! @DanielOmine

Comment: Talvez seja melhor guardar o tipo dos dado em variável.

Comment: O teu código não te permite escrever de outra forma, ou tu assim o queres ?

Comment: @rray não entendi, como faria isso?

Comment: @DanielOmine Só pra constar era isso mesmo, depois que removi as quebras nos `ssss...` que vc sugeriu, e arrumei uma coisinha aqui outra ali (que não tinham nada a ver com o erro da pergunta) funcionou perfeitamente.... valeu!

Comment: @Edilson não entendi, mas fiz um comentário na sua resposta... valeu.

Comment: Os espaços em branco tbm fazem diferença, to fazendo uns testes aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espaços ou quebras de linhas são interpretados pelo MYSQLi como um dos tipos de placeholder o erro gerado é:

> Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in

Qualquer caracter diferente dos tipos definidos na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) `sidb` gera o erro, `x` é caracter inválido e `n` é a posição +1.

> Undefined fieldtype x (parameter n)

### Simulação do erro

```
CREATE TABLE `pessoas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idade` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profissao` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Arquivo de teste

```
<?php

$nome = 'teste '. rand(0, 5000);
$idade = rand(1,120);
$profissao = 'pro';


$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'web');
$sql = "INSERT INTO pessoas (nome, idade, profissao) VALUES(?,?,?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

//quebra de linha proposital
$stmt->bind_param('s
ss', $nome, $idade, $profissao);

if(!$stmt->execute()){
    echo '<br>Erro: SQLState:'. $db->errno . ' Descrição: '. $db->error;
}else{
    echo 'sucesso';
}
```

A saída do teste acima e da variante entende que foram definidos quatro tipos e passados apenas três valores(variáveis).

```
$stmt->bind_param('s ss', $nome, $idade, $profissao);
--------------------^
```

é a mesma:

> Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in

**Outros exemplos curiosos**

```
$stmt->bind_param('aaa', $nome, $idade, $profissao);
$stmt->bind_param('   ', $nome, $idade, $profissao);
```

Saída:

> Undefined fieldtype **a** (parameter **2**) in

### Soluções

Para manter organizada a definição dos tipos, sugiro que defina uma padrão e atribuia isso à uma variável e remova os caracteres inválidos com `str_replace()`.

```
$invalidos = array("\n","\r", "\r\n", " ");
$tipos ='s
s
s';

$tipos = str_replace($invalidos, "",$tipos);
$stmt->bind_param($tipos, $nome, $idade, $profissao);
```

O insert é realizado sem problemas. Outra solução mais simples é passar o número de parâmetros para `str_repeat()` fazer o trabalho, no exemplo utilizei de proposito todos os valores como `s` acredito que essa tipagem não serve para nada em 90% ou o uso deles não é nenhum pouco óbvio.

**Solução alternativa**

```
$tipos = str_repeat('s', 3);
$stmt->bind_param($tipos, $nome, $idade, $profissao);
```

Comment: Ohhhhhh aí sim hein!! Matou a cobra e mostrou o pau! :-)

Comment: @gustavox ... essas coisa de tipar parâmetros ta me tirando do serio, parace não servir para nada ... no pdo é a mesma coisa tem um caso que faz a diferença ... sei la talvez faça a diferença em stored procedures ...

Comment: É, esse tipo de erro é muito chato, ainda mais pra quem não é experiente... mas pelo menos este tá desvendado. :-) Valeu!

Comment: @gustavox testar com 138 é sacanagem ne? kkk

Comment: kkkkk é que tinha feito outros com 10, 12, e daí resolvei fazer os mais difíceis primeiro...:)

Answer (score 2):

No *PHP*, pode-se quebrar espaços em algumas funções, não há qualquer problema, por exemplo numa *array*:

```
$array = array(
              'indice'=>                     'Valor',
              'indice1'                 => 'Valor' 
              );
```

Nesta função por exemplo, pode-se colocar espaços, desde que os valores nela contigo mantenham a estrutura, ela continua a funcionar, e sem quaisquer problemas.

Mas noutros casos, nem por isso. Vejamos por exemplo quando se trata de *Strings*, *Inteiros*, e outros, normalmente vais obter um erro qualquer como retorno, veja este exemplo:

```
$n = 1.     50; // Quebra o código e retorna um erro de sintaxe;
$n1 = 1.50;     // retorna 1.5 como deveria ser
$string = "E                       u"; // Retorna (E     u) com um espaço inserido
$string1 = "Eu"; // Retorna (eu) do jeito como foi formatado

echo $n . "<br/>"; // A execução do código vai parar nesta linha, por causa da quebra
echo $n1 . "<br/>";
echo $string . "<br/>";
echo $string1 . "<br/>";
```

Acontece que ás vezes não é questão de escrever o código como queremos, mas sim de boas práticas, para que possamos evitar o máximo de erros possíveis, porque também não vamos ficar a escrever o código duma forma inconveniente, que até mesmo nós possamos vir a ter problemas a analisar. Por isso é bom sempre manter as coisas que devem estar ligadas, ligadas, e as que devem estar separadas, separadas, porque mesmo que nós compreendamos o código, apesar dos espaços inseridos, o interpretador na maior parte das vezes não consegue, uma referência a isso, é o exemplo que passei acima.

O único conselho aqui, é manter as boas práticas, e se as pessoas até hoje escrevem os códigos sem os espaços, é porque elas mesmas já devem ter testado. Caso contrário estaríamos a ver espaços nos exemplos oficiais da página do *PHP*, e outras.

Comment: +1 Mas então Edilson, eu só comecei a inserir os espaços depois de ver coisas parecidas no SO (que na verdade não eram espaços, mas quebras de linha, e nunca no lugar onde deu problema aqui...), e somente porque o código estava ficando confuso, muito difícil de "enxergar"... Neste caso, o espaço que estava dando problema era mesmo "devido as quebras de linha no parâmetro de definição de tipos sissssiiiiiissi." como disse o @DanielOmine Depois que removi as quebras e espaços, funcionou perfeitamente...Valeu.

Comment: Já é qualquer coisa.